# Synthesis question: Using reductive amination to form pyrrolidine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, biochemistry, synthesis, organic-reduction

What molecule results from treating 4-oxopentanal with $\ce{NH4Cl}$ and $\ce{NaCNBH3}$? Why? Is this a good, high yield reaction?

I believe that pyrrolidine is formed because amination will convert one carbonyl to an amine that reacts with the other carbonyl. However, I am unsure how reasonable this is and I'm unsure what happens to the original carbonyl oxygen.

Comment: Reductive amination is OK. Succindialdehyde is harder to come by than pyrrolidine.

Comment: The carbonyl oxygens are lost as water during imine formation